# Limit text in a textarea to the actual area of the element

Tags: javascript, html

Most questions I have seen when it comes to TextArea ask about limiting characters. I do not want this. I want to know how to limit the editable area of a TextArea html element to the actual textarea itself. Is this even possible?

Example:

Say I have a TextArea that is 30 columns by 4 rows. You could limit the text in this area to 120 characters, but that won't stop a user from hitting return 5 times and already being past the given area I have set up for it. I don't want a scroll bar to come up.

Is there any javascript that can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the text into a `visibility: hidden` div with font styles equal to the textarea and a `max-width` that won't let it go beyond your number of columns. If the height of the hidden copy of the text exceeds your limit, remove the text that was added.

The following is *close* to what you need. Unfortunately, it doesn't nix the 5th row (after hitting enter on the 4th row) until you type something on it, and it can leave a couple characters on the 5th row (if you wrap to the 5th row from the 4th row). I'm uncertain how to refine the technique further.

```js
var $measure = $('#measure');
var $input = $('#input');
var $output = $('#measurement');

var existingText = '';
$input.on('keyup', function(event) {
    $measure.html($input.val());
    $output.val($measure.width() + 'x' + $measure.height() + 'px');
    if ($measure.height() > 60) {
        $input.val(existingText.trim());
        $measure.html(existingText.trim());
    }
    existingText = $input.val();
});
```

```css
#measure
{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    
    /* set font style equal to style of textarea */
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    word-spacing: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 221px;
    border: 1x solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
<div id="measure"></div>
<br>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="measurement"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution is quite simple and works for me:

1. Style your textarea with '**overflow:hidden**' and '**resize:none**'. This will hide the scroll
   bar and stop the user from resizing the textarea themselves.
2. Set the desired dimensions of your textarea. (i.e. rows="4" cols="50")
3. Use an **input** event handler to compare the height of your text area with the height of the scroll. While the scroll is taller than your textarea remove one character from the end of your input. This loop will continue until the scroll no longer exceeds the height of the textarea (i.e there is no scrollbar and the textarea remains it's desired size).

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  while (textarea.clientHeight < textarea.scrollHeight) {
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.value.length - 1);
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="2" cols="20"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score -2):

Set maxlength attr to 120

Example link is here

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. They can still hit return five times and that would be less than 120 characters